# telegram sends same message continuously

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

The code keeps on receiving the same message continuously.
My code is:

```
var telegram = require('telegram-bot-api');


 var api = new telegram({
        token: token,
        updates: {
            enabled: true
    }
});



api.on('message', function(message)
{

    // Received text message
    var from=(message.from.id);
    console.log(from);
    var first_name=(message.from.first_name);
    var last_name=(message.from.last_name);
    var msg=message.text;


});
```

even i send only 1 message... the **console.log(from)** outputs continuously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using the getUpdates method in order to fetch the updates, you should set the offset. Identifier of the first update to be returned. Must be greater by one than the highest among the identifiers of previously received updates. By default, updates starting with the earliest unconfirmed update are returned. An update is considered confirmed as soon as getUpdates is called with an offset higher than its update_id. The negative offset can be specified to retrieve updates starting from -offset update from the end of the updates queue. All previous updates will forgotten.
here you can read more: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates

just change your code like this:

```
// Create a bot that uses 'polling' to fetch new updates
var api = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
```

Comment: well at first you should provide more information about the way you get the updates? is it long pooling or short pooling? are you using web hook? if you are using web hook you should remember to return http 200 at the response, unless telegram keep sending the same update to you.

Comment: I am not using webhook

Comment: ok. what do you return as your web hook response? you can call it manually at see what is it? probably you don't return 200 code in your response.

Comment: David, I am not using webhook

Comment: sorry. my bad. then just like my answer, you should try to send the offset. its simple. you can try it on your browser. just call the method like this: https://api.telegram.org/bot***/getUpdates?offset=1

Comment: then increase the offset value.

Comment: every time i increased the offset i got the same update_id

Comment: Thank you very much david...I am able to get the new messages..but do u have any idea on how to set the offset=update_id+1 in nodejs

Comment: you are welcome dear @sajeet. as i said before please tell me what library you are using?

Comment: I am using node "telegram-bot-api"

Comment: in that case define your bot like this: const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

Comment: glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are sending a response back. I was using `expressjs`, and I forgot to do `res.json` (or `res.send`), hence Telegram constantly tried to update the state of the webhook.